# IE striping headers from HTTP POST request to S3

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, http, post, amazon-s3

I'm doing straight-to-S3 multipart file upload via AJAX. Everything works fine under all browsers but IE.

S3 requires an `Authorization` HTTP header in each POST request which contains the signature of the file slice being uploaded.

It appears IE strips out this header from the request, yielding a 403 response.
What's more funny is that IE does not strip another custom S3 header: `x-amz-date`.

Any idea how I can force the 'Authorization' header in?

As requested, here is my code :

```
initiateUpload: function() {
  var response = this.sign({method:'POST', path: this.key + '?uploads'});
  this.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: response.url,
    headers: {
      'x-amz-date': response.date,
      'Authorization': response.signature
    },
    onLoad: this.uploadParts.bind(this)
  });
},

request: function(params){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (params.onLoad) xhr.addEventListener("load", params.onLoad, false);
  if (params.onUploadStart) xhr.upload.onloadstart = params.onUploadStart;
  if (params.onUploadProgress) xhr.upload.onprogress = params.onUploadProgress;
  xhr.open(params.method, params.url, true);
  for (h in params.headers)
    xhr.setRequestHeader(h, params.headers[h]);
  xhr.send(params.body);
},
```

Comment: maybe this might be of some help stackoverflow.com/a/15003213/1236044
Also, you should post the code for your ajax call